# How to manage importing an SCons project

Tags: c++, build, scons

I have an SCons-based project that has a rather specialized SConstruct file (due to CUDA), let's call it project A. I am using it as a submodule for another project I am working on we can call project B that is also going to have some rather peculiar compilation requirements (due to MEX).

I'd like to leave project A effectively untouched as it is a common library in my group. How do I get project B to get all of the include, library, etc. information that it needs in order to "compile through". In CMake this would effectively just be a combination of `add_subdirectory()` and `target_link_libraries()`. Is there an equivalent concept in SCons or is an SConstruct more strictly standalone (can't be called by another SConstruct)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*this was too long for a comment, not sure it's an "answer"...*)

SConstructs are unique top-level things, but then again, they also aren't - you can call any file when you call `SConscript()`, including one named `subdir/SConstruct`, as long as the latter is structured in a way that has that make sense, and having A `Export()` things that projects that called it would be interested in `Import()`ing.

There's also nothing to stop you from writing a really minimal SConstruct for A which does *only* things that might be unique to building A standalone, and all the real (common) work is done by an SConscript which A's SConstruct calls, but which B's SConstruct can also call.

Or, you could add a step to A that writes all the variable information you think project B needs into a file, say `exports.py` in the form of assignment statements, and have B read that in with a `Variables(files="exports.py")` call - this is a bit like doing `Export` and `Import` but across the boundary of scons calls. If the file doesn't exist, assume you have to make a call to scons to run A's build, so the file serves as the sync point for two independent builds.

You might also be able to do something with the `ParseConfig` function, if you write a script to call which munges the information from A into a form B can consume.

All of these do imply *some* changes to A's build, however.  They should be harmless from A's viewpoint: writing a file or exporting some variables is a throwaway operation unless someone is listening for those - assuming A's build is suitably clean.

Maybe some thoughts from here (though not exactly the same case) might be applicable? https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/SconstructMultiple